# Adafruit_NeoPixel and serial communication

Tags: arduino, serial-port, avr

I using Adafruit_NeoPixel from https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel
and I have problem about serial communication with my board, but it's work fine when i don't use pixels.show(); I have no idea why, but anyone can explain this, and how to fix this.(I have to refresh led overtime too)
*sorry for my English

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif

#define PIN            6
#define NUMPIXELS      16

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

int delayval = 500;
void setup() {

#if defined (__AVR_ATtiny85__)
  if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
#endif

  pixels.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  for(int i=0;i<NUMPIXELS;i++){
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0,150,0));
    pixels.show();
  }
}

void serialEvent() {
  if(Serial.available()){
    delay(5);
    size_t len = Serial.available();
    char rcvData[128];
    Serial.readBytes( rcvData, len );
    rcvData[len] = '\0';

    Serial.write(rcvData);
    Serial.write('\n');
  }
}
```

Serial input

```
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
```

Serial Output

```
12679
12349
123459
12456789
12569
126789
12389
12389
12389
abdefklqrs
abfghijklmnopqrs
abghmnos
abcdijkpqs
abfglmns
abcdijopqs
abefglmnrs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if u read the [Adafruit_NeoPixel::show](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel/blob/master/Adafruit_NeoPixel.cpp#L111) part, it's because of the crucial timing.

> **note:**  Data latch = 50+ microsecond pause in the output stream.  Rather than
>      put a delay at the end of the function, the ending time is noted and
>      the function will simply hold off (if needed) on issuing the
>      subsequent round of data until the latch time has elapsed.  This
>      allows the mainline code to start generating the next frame of data
>      rather than stalling for the latch.
>
> **while(!canShow());**
>      endTime is a private member (rather than global var) so that mutliple
>      instances on different pins can be quickly issued in succession (each
>      instance doesn't delay the next).
>      In order to make this code runtime-configurable to work with any pin,
>      SBI/CBI instructions are eschewed in favor of full PORT writes via the
>      OUT or ST instructions.  It relies on two facts: that peripheral
>      functions (such as PWM) take precedence on output pins, so our PORT-
>      wide writes won't interfere, and that interrupts are globally disabled
>      while data is being issued to the LEDs, so no other code will be
>      accessing the PORT.  The code takes an initial 'snapshot' of the PORT
>      state, computes 'pin high' and 'pin low' values, and writes these back
>      to the PORT register as needed.
>
> **noInterrupts();**  Need 100% focus on instruction timing

Hope this answeres your question